# vb.net Switch between images on button click

Tags: vb.net, image, button, onclick

So I have 2 PNGs that I am using instead of the button. I set the button image as image 1 and have both the images in my resources. How do I switch them back and forth when I click the button?

Lets call the images lunch.png and breakfast.png

I tried toying around with the select case and If statement...

Please nothing too complicated as this is I am just learning VB and would like to understand what I am writing in.

Comment: show what you have tried and what doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub picboxSub_Ass_Detail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Click

    If  picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Tag = 0 Then
        picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Image = My.Resources.Tamp02
         picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Tag = 1
        GoTo a
    ElseIf  picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Tag = 1 Then
        picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Image = My.Resources.Tamp01
         picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Tag = 0
        GoTo a
    End If
    a:
End Sub
```

I have used the picture to click and change here, the name is just the name is what i have called it it could easily just be **picturebox1**. Make sure to set the picture tag to 0 first :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to track the currently selected meal type.  In the example below I've setup an enum to represent the two different meal types, and a public property with a private backing field to represent the current state:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Enum MealType
        Breakfast
        Lunch
    End Enum

    Private _Meal As MealType = MealType.Breakfast

    Public Property Meal As MealType
        Get
            Return _Meal
        End Get
        Set(value As MealType)
            _Meal = value
            Select Case _Meal
                Case MealType.Breakfast
                    Button1.Image = My.Resources.Breakfast

                Case MealType.Lunch
                    Button1.Image = My.Resources.Lunch

            End Select
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub SwapMeal()
        If Meal = MealType.Breakfast Then
            Meal = MealType.Lunch
        Else
            Meal = MealType.Breakfast
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Meal = MealType.Breakfast
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SwapMeal()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's a shorter, less beautiful version, keeping the boolean for each Button in its Tag() property.  Note that the btn_Click() method is handling Button1, Button2 and Button3:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Button1.Tag = False
        Button2.Tag = False
        Button3.Tag = False
        Button1.PerformClick()
        Button2.PerformClick()
        Button3.PerformClick()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        btn.Tag = Not CBool(btn.Tag)
        btn.Image = If(CBool(btn.Tag), My.Resources.Breakfast, My.Resources.Lunch)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Well... It works... Which is great so thank you! Not so much for simple though... any way to make it less than 40 lines?

Comment: Less isn't necessarily better...but feel free to dissect and refactor it to your hearts content.

Comment: Ok that's awesome but now I have a problem when I try to duplicate the code to use on another button I face issues like a) the 1st button won't go to the default img and b) when I click the 2nd button 1st time nothing happens and then on the 2nd click it works

Comment: You have to have a separate variable for each Button.  One solution is to keep the boolean variable in the **Tag()** property of the button.

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me:

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.CheckedChanged

```
    If Button1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        Button1.Image = My.Resources.icon1
    Else
        Button1.Image = My.Resources.icon2
    End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, using an integer variable which has a default value of `0` triggers the `if` condition on button click, and the value of `a` becomes `1`. Then, on second click, the `if` condition fails, and the else triggers. It changes the value of `a` to `0`. Again, the process repeats each time the button is clicked.

```
dim a As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Button1.Click
   If a=0 Then
      Button1.image = My.Resources.image1
      a=1
   Else
      Button1.image = My.Resources.image2
      a=0
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean how do you change an image when the user presses a button? Just use the below code to change the image to lunch.png.

```
PictureBoxName.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("lunch")
```

and for breakfast.png use this.

```
PictureBoxName.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("breakfast")
```

Comment: I got that much. I mean there's only 1 button and when I click it the image changes from one to another back and forth